# Retaking a Course in Phd that I Took During the Master

Tags: phd, graduate-school, policy

I took a course in my Master degree and I got (B). After I got my degree I applied to the Phd program in the same campus. When I started my Phd program I retook the course and got (A). I submitted my plan of study for the PhD and it was approved by my department. However, the grad school rejected my plan of study and wants me to use the old grade since it was used in the Master. They don't want me to use the new grade at all. The (B) will affect  my GPA and I'd have to take another course to meet the required GPA.

I want to know, why the grad school rejected the repeated course? and what should I do?

Comment: You need to discuss the specifics of why the school rejected the repeat course with your grad school. There may be a no repeat rule for grades above a C. You may also have an appeals process available, but we wouldn't know that.

Comment: For my specific university BOTH grades would be used for the GPA calculation. Redoing a course does not remove the previous grade. Although our institution is currently reviewing this policy. Not recognizing the new grade at all seems a bit silly in my eyes.